# A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition, Bayes decision

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

Let $Y = +1(-1)$ if a person succeeds (fails) in the exam. Suppose $Y$ depends only on the two variables $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is the hours of partying time per week and $B$ is an intangible unknown quantity. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are independent uniform [0,4] random variables and $Y$ = 1 if and only if $AB \leq 4$

(a) find the Bayes decision if no variable is available and if only $A$ is available.

I know that the Bayes Decision looks like this:

\begin{equation}
    P(Y=1) = \frac{1}{16}\int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{min(4, 4/a)} 1dadb
\end{equation}

Can someone, please, explain why are we integrating over 1?

In the book "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition" the author is integrating over the regressor function; as I understand in our case it is $A*B$ ?
Could someone clarify these points and provide a resource where Bayes decision and Loss calculations are explained in a more detailed way?

Comment: Since $A,B$ are independent, the pair $(A,B)$ is uniformly distributed in the square $[0,4]\times[0,4]$. The integral is finding the area of the region in the square consisting of points $(a,b)$ that satisfy $ab\le4$. The desired probability is the ratio of this area to the area of the whole square.

Comment: Alternatively, you can think of the $1/16$ as coming from a probability density function factor $p(a,b)=p(a)p(b)=\frac14\frac14$ that has been moved outside the integral sign (leaving just the "1" inside).

Comment: However, note that the OP has written the differentials in the wrong order for the stated limits of integration; i.e., given that the inner integral is over the interval $[\min(4, 4/a)]$, it must be w.r.t. variable $b$: $$P(Y=1) =\int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{\min(4, 4/a)}\frac{1}{16}\,db\,da= \int_{0}^{4} \left(\int_{0}^{\min(4, 4/a)} \frac{1}{16}\,db\right)\,da.$$

Comment: nice interpretation, thank you. r.e.s you are right, the order should be different.